# Notation for dual and adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

This is just an unexciting question about notation.

Let $V$, $W$ be vector spaces, $F:V \to W$ a linear map. The *dual* of $F$ is the map $F^*: W^* \to V^*$ defined by $F^*(\alpha)(v)=\alpha(Fv)$ for any $\alpha\in W^*$, $v\in V$. If both spaces are equipped with an inner product we can also define the *adjoint* of $F$, $F^\dagger:W\to V $ defined by
\begin{equation} 
\langle Fv,w \rangle _{W}=\langle v, F^\dagger w \rangle_V
\end{equation}
for any $v\in V, w\in W$.

I have used $*$ for the dual and $\dagger$ for the adjoint. I'd like to know which notations are commonly used in the mathematical literature. I have seen $*$ used for both but of course that is not the best when you have both around and want to distinguish them.

Comment: I think yours is a good choice of notation. I have also seen the ‘, especially to denote the dual, and particularly in the real case. The dagger and the star suggest complex conjugation to me. But there is no real standard, at least in mathematics. In physics I think there is a more unified notation.

Comment: I've seen $F^t$ and $^tF$ and $F^*$ to denote the algebraic dual, and usually $F^\dagger$ denoting a Hermitian adjoint. Usually you can get by without too much confusion, but if there are two different types of adjoint in play, it is well worth sparing a sentence or two to distinguish them.